# login server org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Tags: java, mysql

I´m trying to connect my data base since neatbeans but i have this mistake when i run the program, somebody would help me, thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLo4c.png)

Comment: Can you please remove the image and add the actual error text in your question?

Answer (score 0):

At line number 26, you have `contactos.next()`. Here, `contactos` is `null`, that is why you are getting this error. Check your program and make sure that `contactos` is defined correctly.

Ex: `ResultSet contactos = statement.executeQuery("select * from contactos");`

Also, check for `null` before iterating over this `ResultSet`.